# Fire Shader For Pixelated Fire

Tags: shaders, fire

I learned how to make a voxel fire by importing an OpenVDB of a smoke simulation I had made, and then using the Volume to Mesh modifier to make a cube take the form of the simulation.  I then used the remesh modifier to make it a blocky fire simulation.

So, in essence, it's a 3D object that changes shape over time to look like a fire explosion.

My problem is that I don't know how to make a good shader that would make it look like good fire.  How could I make a shader that portrays an explosion for one mesh?

Comment: is your voxel file one mesh?

Comment: @Chris yes it is.

Answer (score 2):

If it is e.g. a UVSphere with a displace modifier, you could use this shader setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

I know it doesn't look like fire, but i just wanted to show the principle.

To animate your "fire" you can give your texture an object coordinate , use an empty as object and move this empty to get an animation of your displacement.

If you restrict displacement just to z coordinate and give the upper half of the sphere a vector group, which you choose in your modifier and give your shader a bit alpha you can get this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: hey man, thanks for the effort!  Unfortunately I wasn't clear enough when I wrote this.  That's a great setup tho!  Thanks for the effort u put in!